# select a condition as column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As we can have a command like this in **C#** or **Java**

```
return 1 < 2;
```

Is it possible to do something like that in SQL?

```
SELECT 1 < 2
```

or in my case:

```
Select
    Case when sign = '<' then col1 < 10 else col1 > 10 end
from ...
```

> Result: 0

When I use `SELECT 1 < 2` I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '<'.

So it seems that there is a problem with this statement. I'm using TSQL.

Comment: Not quite clear what you want. Your query will return TRUE for rows where sign = '<' and col1 < 10 etc. Is that what you want?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: "logical fields" are absolutely supported in SQL. The condition shown in the question are valid standard SQL expressions

Comment: I get some error with that command that I put it in mypost. I use Tsql but if there is a general command that's better to me to use in mysql

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm exactly looking for this. But I get error when run the my code! What's the problem with SELECT 1 < 2 ?

Comment: I'm using Sql Server

Comment: Neither SQL Server nor MySQL support that because they do not have a boolean data type. Your only workaround for that is to return `0` and `1` from the case expression as show in Hmiesphera's answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157780/discussion-between-siamak-ferdos-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what DBMS you are using, I am using T-SQL in this example. This should work:

```
declare @col1 int
declare @sign varchar(1)
set @col1 = 10
set @sign = '<'

Select
    case when (@sign = '<') and (@col1 < 10) then 1 
         when (@sign = '>') and (@col1 > 10) then 1
         else 0
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this:

```
DECLARE @Col1 INT = 10; --Set your value

SELECT Result = CASE WHEN @Col1 > 10 THEN CAST(@Col1 AS VARCHAR(10) ) + ' > 10'
                     WHEN @Col1 < 10 THEN CAST(@Col1 AS VARCHAR(10) ) + ' < 10'
                     ELSE CAST(@Col1 AS VARCHAR(10) ) + ' = 10'
                     END
```

OR

```
DECLARE @Col1 INT = 10;
DECLARE @VarForCompare INT = 55;

SELECT Result = CASE WHEN @Col1 > @VarForCompare THEN CAST(@Col1 AS VARCHAR(10) ) + ' > ' + CAST(@VarForCompare AS VARCHAR(10) )
                     WHEN @Col1 < @VarForCompare THEN CAST(@Col1 AS VARCHAR(10) ) + ' < ' + + CAST(@VarForCompare AS VARCHAR(10) )
                     ELSE CAST(@Col1 AS VARCHAR(10) ) + ' = ' + + CAST(@VarForCompare AS VARCHAR(10) )
                     END
```

OR using IF:

```
IF @Col1 > @VarForCompare
    SELECT CAST(@Col1 AS VARCHAR(10) ) + ' > ' + CAST(@VarForCompare AS VARCHAR(10) ) Result
        ELSE
            IF @Col1 < @VarForCompare
                SELECT CAST(@Col1 AS VARCHAR(10) ) + ' < ' + CAST(@VarForCompare AS VARCHAR(10) ) Result
                    ELSE
                            SELECT CAST(@Col1 AS VARCHAR(10) ) + ' = ' + CAST(@VarForCompare AS VARCHAR(10) ) Result
```

I don't see why you need `Sign` variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when 1 <2 then 'true' else 'false' end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the inline if statement instead of CASE:

```
SELECT IIF(1 < 2,'true','false')
```